# Suggested Edit does not have any changes

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

What should I make of this suggested edit? Other times when I see something like this, I'll switch between "rendered" and "markdown" but there is no such option here. Can there be a way to detect such "non-edits" automatically?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2355081

[image]

**bug**: html is stripped from the "markdown" view in tag edit suggestions.

Comment: The edit itself seems appropriate; it seems that the suggested edit isn't properly rendering the change.

Comment: I'll take your word for it and mark as approved.

Comment: Well, when you look at the actual tag wiki there are `<p>` tags surrounding the content, showed in plain text (not rendered).  The edit comment indicates it's removing them.  I think that the HTML is stripped out of the markup shown on the edit review screen (which is the bug; they should be shown as it renders).

Comment: Thanks, I added that to clarify the purpose of the question.

Comment: If it’s a bug, it’s [a pretty serious bug](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4889825/edit/d8edc83e-3005-43d0-b0e5-8425cead54ff). (That’s the previous revision.)

Comment: I'm getting an error on that link: "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes."